# Get log data from LogAnalytics Workspace using Rest API

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to fetch log data from Azure Log Analytics workspace with the queries that I have saved inside the workspace. I have started developing a Web API to fetch the results of the query and I registered this Web API to an Azure Active Directory that I created inside my Visual Studio Enterprise Azure subscription. But when I try to 'Request Permission' for LogAnalytics API, I am not able to find LogAnalytics API from Microsoft API. I am following the instructions in the following link:
https://dev.loganalytics.io/oms/documentation/1-Tutorials/1-Direct-API
[image]

Can someone please let me know how can i fetch log data from inside LogAnalytics workspace? I have looked into Microsoft documentation which just gives the API but does not say how to get the token:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/savedsearches/get

Comment: you can refer to [this doc](https://dev.loganalytics.io/documentation/Tools/CSharp-Sdk). and please let me know if you still have more issues about that.

Comment: Microsoft.Azure.OperationalInsights this package is not available in Nuget

Comment: I will check it later. you want to get the logs from log analytics, or execute the query saved in log analytics?

Comment: I want to executed the saved queries in log analytics using Rest API and get the result back in the form of json

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But when I try to 'Request Permission' for LogAnalytics API, I am not able to find LogAnalytics API from Microsoft API.

You need to navigate to the `APIs my organization uses`, search for the `Log Analytics API`, add the `Application permission` like below.

**Note:** The [link](https://dev.loganalytics.io/oms/documentation/1-Tutorials/1-Direct-API) you provided should be out of date, it uses the `Delegated permission`, that is not correct, it must be `Application permission`, because we will use the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the token.

[image]

[image]

After giving the permission, also make sure your AD App has an RBAC role e.g. `Contributor`, `Log Analytics Reader` in the `Access control (IAM)` of your workspace, if not, follow this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/quickstart-assign-role-user-portal) to add it.

Then use the client credential flow to get the token, after getting the token, use it to call the api.

```
POST /YOUR_AAD_TENANT/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&resource=https://api.loganalytics.io
&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
```

For more details, you could refer to this [link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sentinel/access-azure-sentinel-log-analytics-via-api-part-1/ba-p/1248377), don't miss any step.

---

> I have looked into Microsoft documentation which just gives the API but does not say how to get the token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/savedsearches/get

To get the token for this REST API, it is the same with the `Log Analytics API`. To call this API, no need to add the API permission for your AD App, it just needs the RBAC role. The difference is you need to change the `resource` in the request body to `https://management.azure.com` like below.

```
POST /YOUR_AAD_TENANT/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&resource=https://management.azure.com
&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET
```

For more details, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#client-credentials-grant-non-interactive-clients).

Comment: Giving Log Analytics API permission to the SPN is no longer needed, if you have enough(contributor) RBAC access to the workspace